# Python: excel saved file with openpyxl show weird symbol when opened with a text editor

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

I've created with tkinter an app that help me analyze a .txt file and save information in a excel file. The app works (no problem in saving or opening the file and is readable). I save my variable in the file using openpyxl this code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
[...]
 def excel(self):
       wb = load_workbook('F:\\Python\\template\\excel_template.xlsx')
       sheet = wb.active

       sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value  = "HADS"
       sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value  = HADS1
       sheet.cell(row=3, column=1).value  = HADS2   

       sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value  = "date" 
       sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value  = date1 
       sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value  = date2   
[...]

       filename = "F:\\Python\\file\\" name + "_" + year + ".xlsx"
       wb.save(filename)
```

When I tried to upload it in my Djano website I got various error. I thought the problem could it be the separetor and so I opened my excel file with a text editor and this is what I found inside:

```
PK    ôTAMb   ±      docProps/app.xmlMŽ=1DÿÊq½·AÁBb@ÐR°²{/dC²B~¾9ÁnoFß
g*â©-†Tã"’ Š¶N]§n—h¥cy ;ç‘ÎŒÏHI`«Ô¨  ¥™æMþŽFŸr­xNæê±pe'Ã¥!
ÿrmÞ©Ô5ï&õ–Öð;i^PK    ôTÌS2±ì   Ç     docProps/core.xml•ÑMK1à¿RrßM×Ò€(žTŠ·LÛÅÍÉÈÖïvm·•zñ˜™wžŒ4Q˜ð9…ˆ‰Ì“k}&.Ù–(
€l¶èt.û„ï›ëœ¦þ™6µùÐ„iUÍÁ!i«IÃ,â(²iÍHÆÏÔ€5€-:ô”—NYÂäòŸCgLîr3¦º®+»zÈõqx{|x–/ŸI{ƒLIk„I¨)$uãŸ´„³‚<üûS@;éuA_—ìØy­oïV÷LM+>+ªyQÍVüZð…¨¯Þ÷Ö¯ùè‚mÖÍ?ÅÅ™x”„‹›©oPK    ôT:€Ý—‡  c.     xl/theme/theme1.xmlíZOoÛ6¿÷Sº»–dý±‹º…-Ûí–¤-š´C´L[l(Ñ ©$FQ ×]è†]ì¶Ã0 ÀvÚý6-¶ØW%ÿ‰dK6ím“Æ‚„äû½Çß{zï‘Ö¿¾¾yû,$à1ŽiÔÔŒëºPäÓŽFMíÑQ¯R× 0@B#ÔÔ&ˆk·o]»    oˆ …Hñˆß€M-b|£Zå¾†ü:£HÎ
)¡ÿ²QuÀà©„
```

Usually when I open an Excel file with my text editor I would find my variables normally written. I'm doing something wrong while saving my file? Is there another way? I really don't need the template and I would be fine saving the file in a .csv format if this could be help solve the problem.
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: It's an excel file, you're not supposed to open it with a text editor. It's encoded in a different format, kinda like opening a `.mp3` with notepad, Try saving the file as `.csv` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I just openened it to see what separetor the file was using. I've always done this and I always saw my variable normaly written. I can't upload the file in my Django website because of of error like ``` error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 11, saw 4 ``` and I thought that it could be the source of the problem since I open without problem all the excel file except the one written with the app

Comment: That's probably because the files you've been opening in the past is of the `.csv` format, which can be opened with a text editor.

Comment: XLSX files are zip files, which is why you see PK at the start of the file. Your code contains nothing related to the Django exception. We need this to be able to help you.